# A simple (?) equality of two initial $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm afraid I miss the forest for the trees....

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(E,\mathcal{B}_E)$ be a state space and $\mathcal{E}$ a generating $\pi$-system of $\mathcal{B}_E$. If I now take a random measure $\mathcal{N}$  - that is a random element on $(M(E),\mathcal{M}(E))$, where $M(E)$ is the set of all measures on $(E,\mathcal{B}_E)$ and $\mathcal{M}(E):=\sigma(m_A,A\in\mathcal{B}_E)$ is the inital $\sigma$-algebra wrt the maps $m_A:(M(E),\mathcal{M}(E)\to([0,\infty],\mathcal{B}_{[0,\infty]}), \nu\mapsto\nu(A)$.

Then I have already shown that the $\mathcal{F}$-$\mathcal{M}(E)$-measurability of $N$ is equivalent to the measurability of $N_A:=m_A\circ N:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\to([0,\infty],\mathcal{B}_{[0,\infty]}), \omega\mapsto N(\omega,A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{B}_E$. Then I have shown that both conditions are again equivaltent to the measurability of $N_A$ for all $A\in\mathcal{E}$.

I feel that this should easily imply that $\sigma(m_A,A\in\mathcal{B}_E)=\sigma(m_A,A\in\mathcal{E})$, but I just do not see why. Any help is very much appreciated!